# Add a bounce effect to a flip animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cabasicanimation

I animated a flip for a pie chart I have. Here is my code"

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
scaleAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.pieChart addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];
```

`animationDidStop:finished:`

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
[self.pieChart addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scale"];
```

How can I add a bounce effect to the second animation? (The animation in `animationDidStop:finished:`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` instead of two `CABasicAnimation`:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
scaleAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0), @(0.5), @(0.9), @(1)];
scaleAnimation.values = @[@(1.0), @(0.5), @(1.1), @(1.0)];
scaleAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
scaleAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
```

With `keyTimes` and `values`, you can specify multiple stances in your animation.  Here, I made it start with a scale of 1, animating to a scale of 0.5 (your first animation values), then 1.1 (an overshoot to create a "bounce") and finally 1 (your second animation values).  Tweak those to your liking!

If you want to do this animation in two parts, you can keep your first animation, then start a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` in the `animationDidStop:finished:` similar to this instead:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
scaleAnimation.keyTimes = @[@(0), @(0.8), @(1)];
scaleAnimation.values = @[@(0.5), @(1.1), @(1.0)];
scaleAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
scaleAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
```

---

If you instead want to use UIView animation blocks, you'll need to do something similar to this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.squareView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.6 initialSpringVelocity:0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.squareView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

You will probably want to play with the params to tweak the animation.

Comment: Thanks!! Would it be possible to do that in `[UIView animateWithDuration...]`?

Comment: @Jessica I edited my answer to provide an alternative using two `CAAnimation`, and another using `UIView` animation blocks (you will need two).